# What does this cronjob mean? /usr/bin/find /export/events -name "*.cut.mp4" -print0 | head -100 | xargs -0 rm "{}

Tags: cron

```
/usr/bin/find /export/events -name "*.cut.mp4" -print0 | head -100 | xargs -0 rm "{}
```

I wanted to find all file names with `.cut.mp4` and print them out and remove them.

Comment: `-print0 | head` What does head do if it encounters a null terminator instead of a line? I would bet that it ends up including the entire find output, on the basis that it's all one "line."

Comment: you'll need `head -z` if you're using GNU head

Comment: Thank you very much. It included the entire output of the find command.